# What is the difference between autoboxing and coercion?

Tags: java, c, autoboxing, coercion, type-coercion

I program in Java, C and Python.

> The rule for automatic coercions among arithmetic types have been
> augmented to handle the richer set of types

Source: "The C Programming Language"

But what does "coercion" mean? The answers say it's like type conversion and implicit casts and implicit type conversions and called autoboxing where I read it.

What is the difference between autoboxing and coercion?

Comment: [First result on google for `programming coercion`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Comment: auto-boxing is something completely different, and wasn't in the original question.  Specifically, auto-boxing is a Java feature that (implicitly) wraps a primitive value into its "Object" variety, e.g. an `int` into an `Integer`.  The reverse can happen too, e.g. an `Integer` can be automatically unboxed into an `int` value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Coercion is another name for an *implicit* type cast, i.e. one mandated by the language rules, and not explicitly added by the programmer.

Answer (score 6):

Coercion refers to "type coercion". In other words, you add a variable of type `Integer` to a `Float`, the `Integer` will be coerced to `Float`, and the numbers added together.

Answer (score 0):

Coercion is the process of changing one data type into another. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Comment: Do state the difference between the two.