# Why does {. . . .0} evaluate to {}?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax, number-literal

I just found `{....0}` in friend's code. Evaluating it in console returns `{}` (empty object).

Why is that? What is the meaning of 4 dots in JavaScript?

Comment: Viewed almost 2500 times in 6 hours? It appears your *friend* is using the **spread operator** in a different context.

Comment: This is more of a "how this expression is parsed" question. Type this in JS console and you'll notice that the 4th dot is colored differently... same color as zero.

Comment: [Always relevant](https://i.imgflip.com/2pszeo.jpg)

Comment: @JeremyHarris the magic of HNQ

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Four dots actually have no meaning. `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and `.0` is short for `0.0`.

Spreading 0 (or any number) into an object yields an empty object, therefore `{}`.

Comment: `Spreading 0 (or any number) yields an empty object` not necessarily if you spread a number at any other places apart from an object, it will throw an error eg [...0] throws an error.

Comment: @HiteshKumar Spreading non-iterable objects inside an array will indeed throw an error, but that has nothing to do with this question. I am referring to the object-spread mentioned. :)

Comment: NikxDa I think that @HiteshKumar made an important point. It's better to be more explicit about cases where your statements holds true.
`Spreading 0 (or any number) in object literal yields an empty object`
Contains more useful information..

Comment: @Mist I've updated the answer. I don't think it's needed, but it might be good for clarification. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @NikxDa thanks. I like to think about such statements to be more 'complete' when you have the ability to cut them from context, paste elsewhere and they still hold all the information and are educative & informative.

Comment: @Mist You're right, that argument makes total sense. Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 56):

Three dots in an object literal are a *spread property*, e.g.:

```
  const a = { b: 1, c: 1 };
  const d = { ...a, e: 1 }; // { b: 1, c: 1, e: 1 }
```

The last dot with a 0 is a number literal `.0` is the same as `0.0`. Therefore this:

```
 { ...(0.0) }
```

spreads all properties of the number object into the object, however as numbers don't have any (own) properties you get back an empty object.

Comment: You lead me to thinking - I can spread any variable, and own keys will be spread into the new object? 

It works for `Function` `(function x() {}), (x.k = 'v'), ({...x})// {k: 'v'}`
but doesn't work for `Number` `(x = 10), (x.k = 'v'), ({...x}) // {}`

Comment: @mist because numbers (and other primitives) get "boxed" into objects when you work with them as objects, and "unboxed" directly afterwards. Therefore `x.k` will get lost.

Comment: What does 'boxed' means exactly? E.g. when I used the dot operator (property) I worked with the number as object. If I am correct, that's just one case. Are there other cases when 'boxing' is happening?

Does it apply only to numbers? Is there a perf reason or something?
I guess this is for other question, and I should study it further. Could you point me to some book or something?

Comment: @mist It applies to all primitives (number, boolean, string), and it means that `x.k` is the same as `(new Number(x)).x`, and thats because JavaScript's design philosophy is *everything is an object* and thats how they implemented it (not the most elegant solution though in my eyes)

Comment: @mist see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067261/is-boxing-coercion-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks! I see why my key on number couldn't work. Yayy boxing!

Comment: Numbers don't have any _own enumerable_ properties. But they do have properties.

Comment: @patrick which one? AFAIK it only inherits properties fr om its prototype.

Comment: Correct, but those are still properties. They're just inherited and non-enumerable.

Answer (score 6):

In a simple terms `{...}` spread operator in javascript extends one object/array with another.

So, when babelifier tries extending one with another, it has to identify whether it is trying to extend an array or an object.

In the case of `array`, it iterates over elements.

In the case of `object`, it iterates over keys.

In this scenario, the babelyfier is trying to extract keys for `number` by checking the Object's `own property call` which is missing for `number` so it returns empty Object.

Answer (score 1):

Spread operator `{...}` allows iterables to expand. It means that those data types that can be defined in form of `key-value` pairs can be expanded. In terms of `Object` we call key-value pair as Object property and it's value whereas in terms of `arrays` we can think index as key and element in array as it's value.

```
let obj = { a: 4, b: 1};
let obj2 = { ...obj, c: 2, d: 4}; // {a: 4, b: 1, c: 2, d: 4}

let arr1 = ['1', '2'];
let obj3 = { ...arr1, ...['3']}; // {0: "3", 1: "2"}
```

In terms of array, as it takes index as key so here it replaces element '1' of `arr1` with '3' because both of them have same index in different array.

With strings too spread operator returns non-empty object. As string is an array of character so it treats string as an array.

```
let obj4 = {...'hi',...'hello'}   // {0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o"}
let obj5 = {...'y',...'x'}   // {0: "x" }
```

But with other primitive data types it return empty object

with Numbers

```
let obj6 = { ...0.0, ...55} // {}
```

with Boolean

```
let obj7 = { ...true, ...false} // {}
```

In conclusion those data types that can be treated in form of key-value pairs when used with spread operator `{...}` returns non-empty object otherwise it returns empty object `{}`